# deploy shiny app on windows server or Linux

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, server

I have developed some shiny apps and search for a proper way to host the app. As far as I know, there may be several ways to do it:

```
1. shiny-server
2. Rstudio connect 
3. shinyapps.io
4. shinyproxy + Docker
```

I get a windows server(2016) but I find that the above host way need to work on the linux, I have tried shinyproxy but it seems not work for my windows server.

Then I find a simpler way:

```
app <- shinyApp(ui, server)
runApp(app, launch.browser=FALSE, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 1234)
```

then I can visit the app via `<my-server-ip>:1234`
It is really straightforward and simple, I have tested it can support multi users, and I can open new R and Rstudio session to run other scripts.

I have still considering if there is any disadvantage for this method? since we also have Linux servers, we are considering if we need to host the app on linux.

Comment: Try installing a VM on your windows box

Comment: we also have a linux server, but I am not sure if it would be better than what I do on windows server just by:runApp(app, launch.browser=FALSE, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 1234)

Comment: No, you may have issues keeping the services up, etc. if you already have a linux box then setup `shiny-server` on it, its not that hard